# Why does Frodo fall into the dead marsh?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, tolkiens-legendarium

In the Two Towers movie, Frodo follows the lights and looks down into the marshes and sees a dead body. Then he "jumps" into the marsh.

Why does he do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the DVD [Production Commentary](http://www.lordoftherings.net/homevideo/homevideo_tt.html) Frodo was overcome by the [marsh gas](https://www.dhs.wisconsin.gov/air/sewergas.htm). He suffers unconsciousness and hallucinations:

> *Yeah, so this is the spectral corpse scene where was shot Frodo on a
>   "[dry for wet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_for_wet)" set and all the ghouls and goblins were shot with high
>   speed cameras on that "dry-for-wet". At Sony Imageworks they did all
>   the shots in this sequence.*
>
> *Basically the idea was that Peter gave us was that these could be real
>   or they could just be these sort of tricks of the light so **you didn't
>   know whether there were actually these ghouls coming after you or whether
>   Frodo was just sort of hallucinating this whole thing** and so we made
>   them a little particulate.*

Comment: +1 this actually answers the question as it was asked

Comment: -1 The question is asking for an in-universe explanation.

Comment: @dodgetgesteamroller - this commentary *does* actually provide an in-universe reason. The out-of-universe reason would talk about dramatic tension and the need to create a bond between frodo and Gollum to heighten the sense of sameness between them.

Answer (score 34):

This doesn't happen in the book.

In the book it's actually **Sam** who falls, and he *doesn't* fall *into* the water:

> Hurrying forward again, Sam tripped, catching his foot in some old root or tussock. He fell and came heavily on his hands, which sank deep into sticky ooze, so that his face was brought close to the surface of the dark mere. There was a faint hiss, a noisome smell went up, the lights flickered and danced and swirled. For a moment the water below him looked like some window, glazed with grimy glass, through which he was peering. Wrenching his hands out of the bog, he sprang back with a cry. 'There are dead things, dead faces in the water,' he said with horror. 'Dead faces!'

The history of the Dead Marshes is that were once the site of a battle before the Black Gate, which is described by Gollum:

> There was a great battle long ago, yes, so they told him when Smeagol was young, when I was young before the Precious came. It was a great battle. Tall Men with long swords, and terrible Elves, and Orcses shrieking. They fought on the plain for days and months at the Black Gates.

This was presumably one of the battles of the Last Alliance, although I don't believe it's ever stated explicitly.

In the book the Marshes are described in a manner that implies they have some malign lingering influence as a result of this.  Gollum describes the Marsh lights thus:

> The tricksy lights. Candles of corpses, yes, yes. Don't you heed them! Don't look! Don't follow them!

And Frodo's description:

> But I have seen them too. In the pools when the candles were lit. They lie in all the pools, pale faces, deep deep under the dark water. I saw them: grim faces and evil, and noble faces and sad. Many faces proud and fair, and weeds in their silver hair. But all foul, all rotting, all dead. A fell light is in them.

It's therefore evident that this malign influence lures travellers into the Marshes, and that Jackson took this scene and changed the emphasis for the movies; understandable in that it's a different medium, but it must be said that Frodo definitely doesn't *jump* in.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80061#comment169456_80063

Comment: WRT "although I don't believe it's ever stated explicitly", according to a Tolkien wiki: ["In the year S.A. 3434 the host of the Last Alliance of Elves and Men fought the forces of Mordor in the Battle of Dagorlad."](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dead_Marshes)

Comment: @BCdotWEB - true, but even that makes no reference to the bodies in the Dead Marshes being those from the battle.  It could just as easily be a later battle, e.g that in the Tale of Years for TA 1944.

Comment: @DarthSatan Gollum's quote is used at the top of [Battle of Dagorlad](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Battle_of_Dagorlad). Plus, it doesn't seem to fit [Battle of the Camp](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Battle_of_the_Camp). Indeed, the bodies are probably from multiple battles, but that isn't the topic of discussion ("presumably one of the battles of the Last Alliance, although I don't believe it's ever stated explicitly").

Comment: @BCdotWEB - I'm more inclined to trust what Tolkien himself actually wrote than I am to trust what somebody else wrote in a wiki.  Although tolkiengateway *is* generally more reliable than the LotR Wikia (which we've previously established contains some outright falsehoods), if you actually go back and read what was written in the books themselves, there is no direct connection and what I said is correct.  Doesn't matter what a wiki says; the books take precedence.

Comment: The question specifically asked about the movie, and this answer is about the book. It doesn't answer the question, why does it have so many votes?

Comment: @MathiasFoster please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up - "Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!" - an answer doesn't have to be *relevant*, it doesn't have to even be *correct*, it just has to be *useful*.  And evidently people felt that this one was.  You're free to vote it down yourself if you feel otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

The marsh lights are known as Will-o'-the-wisp in [folklore from Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will-o%27-the-wisp#Folklore)

> In European folklore, these lights are believed to be spirits of the dead, fairies, or a variety of other supernatural beings which attempt to lead travelers to their demise.

Comment: The question didn't ask anything about the lights.

Comment: The question had "Frodo follows the lights" after he was warned not too, and that's why he fell in.  Hence my answer does answer the question.  The author of the books on which the film is based is English (hence European folklore applies).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes, Tolkien was English; more relevantly, he was interested in and studied various European mythologies. Neither of those facts is sufficient to identify particular elements of his novels as direct copies of elements of folklore.